# Ruby: using Object.send for assigning variables

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
a = Struct.new(:c).new(1)
b = Struct.new(:c).new(2)

a.send(:c)
=> 1

b.send(:c)
=> 2

a.send(:c) = b.send(:c)
```

The last line result in error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
a.send(:c) = b.send(:c)
            ^
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
a.send(:c=, b.send(:c))
```

`foo.bar = baz` isn't a call to the method `bar` followed by an assignment - it's a call to the method `bar=`. So you need to tell `send` to call that method.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the variable name beforehand

```
a.send(:c=, b.send(:c))
```

If `c` is a dynamic variable then you can do it like this

```
c = 'my_key'
a.send("#{c}=", b.send(c))
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the last line to:

```
a.send(:c=, b.send(:c))
```